# How can I successfully transfer my Android Studio project onto my flash drive?

Tags: android, android-studio

Yes I have searched already and found nothing. Anyways I had copy and pasted the file onto my flash drive. But when I try to open the project from my flash drive, the jave files are never there. Only the gradle scripts shows it's files.

Comment: You can just copy your project folder, or use version control such as git to clone another copy.

Comment: use export option for it

Answer (score 2):

Copy the Entire Folder.
On a new PC where you want to access this project, follow the steps below-

1) Open AS.

2) Click Open Project.

3) Import The Project from where you have saved it.(Currently On Your Flash Drive).

Hope I answered your question, I understand this forum is little harsh and strict for beginners(Your -2).